# How to get rid of boiled chicken breast smell?

Tags: chicken, boiling, smell

I boiled sliced chicken breast in plain water for elders. It's their meal. Raw chicken was fresh, but cooked chicken smells not nice. I know it should smell, but I feel bad for them eating this thing.

Is there any tips to get rid of the smell? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "not nice"? Do you just in general not like the smell of boiled chicken, or is this a different, unusual smell?

Comment: Did you slice the chicken before boiling? That's a little abnormal. You'll lose flavor doing it that way. Try looking up proper chicken poaching technique. Some minor changes to technique may yield better results for you!

Comment: "I know it should smell, but I feel bad for them eating this thing"  ... OK, you don't like it, but how do the elders feel about this smell?

Comment: To some (me included), boiled chicken just smells completely horrible.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of simple hacks that you might try to get rid of the smell in the finished dish, which involves adding small amounts of herbs or spices etc. But of course, it needs to ensured that no-one will have any adverse effect with the additives.

Some ideas:

1) Add lemon juice (fresh squeezed is better) and some ground black pepper near the end of boiling. This is a classic combination.

2) Add Bay leaves and whole black peppers in water when you start boiling.

3) Add sage/thyme during the boiling.

Just keep in mind one thing: The smell and taste capability of many elders are diminished, and the plain boiled chicken might not smell too bad for them. and they might be more interested in avoiding anything that might upset their stomach than a better-smelling chicken.

Answer (score -1):

When boiling add some onion, black pepper, rosemary leaf, saffron  (if available ).
Make a pretty good and nice scent broth.